# pre processed here doc

Tags: heredoc, cat, shell

In the example given below, I was expecting the line 
$a=b
in the todel.txt file.
How do I add the here doc text block as it is without processing?

```
[root@localhost]# cat here_example.sh 
#!/bin/sh
cat > todel.txt << heredoc
<?php
$a=b
# this is comment
?>
heredoc

[root@localhost]# cat todel.txt 
<?php
=b
# this is comment
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put quotes around "heredoc":

```
#!/bin/sh
cat > todel.txt << "heredoc"
<?php
$a=b
# this is comment
?>
heredoc
```

Answer (score 1):

From the `bash(1)` man page:

> If any characters in `word` are
>          quoted, the `delimiter` is the result of quote removal on `word`,  and  the
>          lines  in the here-document are not expanded.

```
#!/bin/sh
cat > todel.txt << "heredoc"
<?php
$a=b
# this is comment
?>
heredoc
```